# PHPMailer email not send and not get any error

Tags: php, phpmailer

The below function to send email but got any mail or error :

```
function send_Email($email, $subject, $body ,$cc = '')
{
    $this->Log("Sending email with To: ". $email. "   <br>Subject: ". $subject ."       <br>Body: ".$body);

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->CharSet    = "utf-8";
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
    $mail->Host       = email_host; 
    $mail->Username   = email_username;
    $mail->Password   = email_password;
    $mail->SetFrom('support@xyv.com', 'zzz Support');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('support@xyv.com', 'zzz Support');
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->AddBCC('support@xyv.com');
    $mail->AddBCC('zzz@zzz.com');
    if(!empty($cc)) {
        $mail->addCC($cc);
    }
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->Body     = $body;    

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($mail);echo "</pre>";
    $response = $mail->Send();
    var_dump($response);

    return $response;
}
```

Debug : IN DEBUG MODE NOT GET ERROR
[error_count:protected] => 0

Comment: where did you send the mail? can you test dump the mail first using tools like [FakeSMTP](https://github.com/Nilhcem/FakeSMTP).

Comment: Does this `echo "<pre>"; print_r($mail);echo "</pre>";` prints anything? or the `var_dump`?

Comment: var_dump(false).......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would really help to read the docs and base your code on the examples provided, which show how to get info about errors, and show debug output. You're not getting any output because you're not asking for any. From the example in the readme:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

That will show you the reason for any sending failure. To enable SMTP debug output, do this:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```